# get UITextField text from UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, uitextfield

I have created a Custom UITableViewCell which has a UIlabel and a UITextField.

In my firstViewController i load and show the custom table:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    LoginTableCell *cell = (LoginTableCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LoginTableCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = (LoginTableCell *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }       
    }
```

Then when the user hits "Login" i want to get the UITextField.text value from there and store it into a string.

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {
```

I know this may sound simple, but i have been stuck on this, and can't seem to find the correct answer to solve.

I thought I could do something like this:

```
NSString *user = LoginTableCell.loginTextField.text;
```

but this returns an error of:

```
request for member 'text' in something not a structure or union
```

any help much appreciated

Thanks

Sam

Comment: instead of LoginTableCell.loginTextField.text, use the object name. eg. currentObject.loginTextField.text

Answer (score 1):

In general you can do it like this. Make sure the *indexPath* in the below code is the correct indexPath for the row which has the required textField.

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
LoginTableCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *user = cell.loginTextField.text;
```

Answer (score 0):

IN tableview  didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate, you have to declare a variable for what is in the textfield,and u have to declare it in wherever you want by setting @property @synthesis and use this string as global variable.then u can use this string and wherever u want to display,by setting your textfield.text = your-string;

Comment: ok, but what if there is some text already in the UITextField and the user doesnt select that cell before hitting the Login button?

Comment: your answer looks as though it relies on the user selecting each cell to be able to store the string. That could cause problems, i want to store the string from the uitextfield whether the user selects that tableviewcell or not

Comment: you only want to store the string from the uitextfiled when the user tap the login button right?one more question,where do u want to store this string from the uitextfield.?

Comment: yea, basically there are 4 cells being shown - Username, Password, Customer ID and Device ID. when the user hits LOGIN, i want to store the values from all of these cells into strings. they are then used to validate a login request and also stored in NSUserDefaults

Comment: NSString *myString = myTextField.text; u can use this code for getting a string from the textfield

Comment: but the textFields that I am trying to get the text from are declared in the Custom UITableViewCell class, and therefore doesnt work